# Mapping data from 2 files imported

Tags: map

I'm not in prog major. This course is needed as an elective for another major. Thus any help is appreciated.

`DataA` and `DataB` imported include:
At `t1=0.5`,
`DataA` has `x1 y1 z1` (1 2 3 for example).
`DataB` has `x2 y2 z2` (11 12 13 for example)
Similarly, at `t2=1`,
All `x y z` are listed in the same manner as at `t1`.

```
DistanceD = Sqrt[(x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2+(z2-z1)^2]
```

What steps are needed to calculate `D1` at `t1`, `D2` at `t2`,...?

My current work:

```
f[x_,y_,z_]:=Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]
```

`dataA = Import dataA` (import from the table file)
`dataB = Import dataB` (import from the table file)

```
newData= dataB-dataA
(Out: {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}) (=difference of x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1)
```

Now I am stuck with evaluating `f` at `newData` results containing `{x,y,z}`. I looked at the `Map` command but still don't know how.
Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: `EuclideanDistance[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}]` should get you started.

Comment: Thank you for introducing the new command. Unfortunately I don't know how to apply for the long list.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. It is considered customary and polite to show your own work and where you got stuck before seeking help on this site. Please add a few entries (say 10) of the long list and how you have attempted a solution. Paste Mathematica code instead of verbal explanations or pictures. Without looking at the structure it is hard to say how to proceed. I think `Map` along with `EuclideanDistance` would be used. Search for `/@` which is an alternative for the `Map` command. Also, if it is relevant, please show how you have imported data from files.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. It's my first time to ask questions; I'll add more detail below.

Comment: Please edit your post with the  details, and avoid using the answer space unless you want to post a detailed answer to your own question.

Comment: Got it and did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using random data and assuming the import is in the same format

```
SeedRandom[123];
dataA = RandomInteger[20, {10, 3}]
dataB = RandomInteger[20, {10, 3}]

MapThread[EuclideanDistance, {dataA, dataB}]
(* {5 Sqrt[2], 15, 3 Sqrt[11], Sqrt[101], Sqrt[62], 
    3 Sqrt[14], Sqrt[62], 9, Sqrt[206], Sqrt[502]} *)
```